# Angular Directive parent template?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have something like:

```
<body>
    <section id="page_content">
        <div myDirective></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

And I want my AngularJS directive to return:

```
<body>
    <div id="newDivFromDirective">
        ...with some stuff inside!
    </div>
    <section id="page_content">
        <div myDirective></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

I currently have:

```
myAngularApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div id="newDivFromDirective" style="display: none">' +
        '...with some stuff inside!' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

But that doesn't return the result I need. I looked into using link - but unsure how I can use template with link too and then get element.parent I guess?

Comment: It is possible, but why do you want to? FYI. It would be easier to put it after the section element, rather than before.  Here is a quick sample that works but is entirely dependent on the html structure being the same http://plnkr.co/edit/FD08cP4aj0InJwf8okeC?p=preview

Comment: It can be after the section too, I just put it before as an example.

It's because we need to have a hovering animation but apply blur class to the section (and keep the animation non-blurred) so have to put the animated div outside the section element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Node.insertBefore()` function to move the element to somewhere else in the link function.  Based on the structure above, you want it to be before the parent element so you need to basically do `grandParentNode.insertBefore(directiveElemNode,parentNode)`.

Here is a simplified directive code that you can use:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>... some text</div>",
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
      var myParent = elem.parent();
      var newParent = myParent.parent();
      newParent[0].insertBefore(elem[0],myParent[0]);
    }
  };
});
```

If as you said you don't mind it being after the `<section>` element then you can also do `myParent.after(elem)`

`Node.insertBefore()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore
Sample plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/FD08cP4aj0InJwf8okeC?p=preview

Comment: Got it working from your comment, and had to add an extra .parent() with: var newParent = elem.parent().parent().parent(); newParent.prepend(elem);